# ManyToOne relation without list/set using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have new JPA project using hibernate and I run into a difficulty while reading its code. I saw:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

...
}
```

and another Entity

```
@Entity
public class Manufacturer{

 private ManufacturerId manufacturerId;

    private String name;

    private Manufacturer() {
    }
...
```

Why there is not List/Set with **Product**(s) in the *Manufacturer* Entity class? **ManyToOne** relationship is Bidirectional?  Why is this possible? How Manufacturer knows about its products, how this will be persisted on the DB table?

Comment: How a manufacturer knows about its products? Your question answers your question. "Its". Its his product. So he would know about it. Every manufacturer small or large has a product portfolio

Comment: ManyToOne is bidirectional if there is a List/Set and unidirectional if there isn't. What more is there to say ...

Comment: @Xelian Are you able to get lists of products from java code without HQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The many-side of an one to many association is optional. You can implement it if intended or skip it if not needed or even risky. A manufacturer could have many thousand of products. Than it makes no sense to fetch all of them at once. It's better to load via a query and use paging. Of course you could add the collection of products to your Manufacturer if you think this helps you.

- Why there is not List/Set with Product(s) in the Manufacturer Entity class?

  Either because not needed or as considered risky.
- ManyToOne relationship is Bidirectional?

  Of course yes. Even if the relationship is not impletemented it still exists.
- Why is this possible? How this will be persisted on the DB table?

  A OneToMany relationship is always implemented by an id on the one side. (ManufacturerId in Products in this case. Nothing else is needed. Even if you implement the products collection. This will not impact the way it's persisted.
- How Manufacturer knows about its products?

  It doesn't. But of course it's possible to query the database.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this answers the question? As it is, it's hard to understand why this is the correct solution.

Comment: @remus Yes, was a bit quick with reading. should be better now.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at it at DB level, table `Product` will have something like `manufacturer_id` which is a foreign key to `Manufacturer` table. The table structure remains the same in both unidirectional and bidirectional mapping case.

Manufacturer will know its product by querying table `Product` with `manufacturer_id = <its id>`. On JPA level, in case of unidirectional mapping you could query it by `from Product p where p.manufacturer.id = :man_id`. In case of bidirectional mapping you could just do `manufacturer.getProducts()`, but it would translate to the same SQL.